# Disable sound when volume keys clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, key, volume

In my application I override `volume up` and `volume down` keys. The problem is that when user click one of these two keys, sound is played. I want somehow to disable/mute this sound.

Here is fragment of my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: {
            // do something when user click volume down key

            return true;
        }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: {
            // do something when user click volume up key

            return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using onKeyDown or onKeyUp still gives the default sound of changing the volume. Use dispatchKeyEvent instead.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        return true;
    default:
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `dispatchKeyEvent` you can detect whenever a button is pressed but you can't detect in which position is the button (up or down). In my example I used `onKeyDown`. This method doesn't remove the sound, so I had to play an infinite sound.

Comment: No, in my example you can see keyCode and use it in the same way. It works, I use this method in my app.

Comment: I am not saying that your method doesn't work, it is alright but not in my situation. I want as I said to detect when the button is in position **up** or **down**. If I press a button (for example  `KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP` ) once, `dispatchKeyEvent` will be called two times, if I do it with `onKeyDown` and `onKeyUp` , they will fire one after the other once, leaving me with more detailed information of the button current state.

Comment: But you can check in dispatchKeyEvent: `if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for myself.
There is a way to stop the sound when volume key is pressed. You need to play an empty sound infinitely, so when user click a volume key it is "trying" to change the media volume, so there isn't click sound played.
You can download an empty sound by searching for `empty sound` and then put it in your `raw` folder in the project.
The last step is just to override the volume keys.

Here is the code you need:

Define MediaPlayer variable.

```
private MediaPlayer infinite_sound;
```

In `onResume()` you need to play the empty sound infinitely.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    infinite_sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.empty);
    infinite_sound.setLooping(true);
    infinite_sound.start();
}
```

In `onPause()` you need to stop the sound.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    infinite_sound.release();
}
```

And finally overriding the actions of the buttons.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN: {
            // Do something when volume down button is clicked

            return true;
        }
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP: {
            // Do something when volume up button is clicked

            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```